# Is there any way to use mice package and the gWQS package together?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to impute the missing values of C1-C3 variables of a large dataset using `mice` package. That has worked so far. The problem arises when I am trying to use the `gWQS` package to conduct mixtures effect X1-X4 chemicals.

I have tried imputing the missing values of my covariates using `mice` package then I have tried using the imputed dataframe in the `gWQS` package to conduct WQS regression. However, my code is not accepted as imp$imp is a list. I have also tried the `miWQS` package however that package has limitations with imputation methods that I do not want to use.

Original dataset comprises of Y as continuous outcome X1-X4 as continuous measures of exposure and C1-C3 as covariates that were imputed with `mice`.

Imputation model using `mice`

```
imp <- mice::mice(originaldf,m=2, meth=meth, pred=pred, 
                  seed=51162,visitSequence="monotone", pri=FALSE)

toxic_chems=c("X1" , "X2",  "X3", "X4")
set.seed(2019)

library("gWQS")
gwqs(Y ~ C1 C2 C3, mix_name=toxic_chems, data=imp$imp,
     q=4, validation=0.8, valid_var=NULL, b=10, b1_pos=F, b1_constr=F, 
     family="gaussian", seed=2019, wqs2=T, plots=T, tables=T)
```

Error:

```
Error in .check.function(formula, mix_name, data, q, validation, valid_var,  : 
                            data must be a data.frame
```

Comment: What is  `str(imp)` ?

Comment: It is a list of 3  created from MICE List of 107
 $ C1 :'data.frame': 156 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ 1: logi [1:156] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ 2: logi [1:156] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ C2:'data.frame': 163 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ 1: logi [1:163] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ 2: logi [1:163] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ C3 :'data.frame': 969 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ 1: num [1:969] 26 10 65 19 49 13 51 54 48 90 ...
  ..$ 2: num [1:969] 92 92 75 87 2 92 16 84 21 20 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already noticed, `mice()` yields a list, namely a list of all your variables with their imputations, in your case *two* imputations, since you've chosen `m=2`. That's how multiple imputation works. Here an example with `nhanes` data included into `mice`:

```
imp <- mice::mice(nhanes, m=2)
imp$imp
# $age
# [1] 1 2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $bmi
#       1    2
# 1  30.1 25.5
# 3  27.2 28.7
# 4  20.4 24.9
# [...]
# 
# $hyp
#    1 2
# 1  1 1
# 4  1 2
# 6  1 2
# [...]
# 
# $chl
#      1   2
# 1  187 187
# 4  131 186
# 10 229 187
# [...]
```

If you'd use OLS, the standard way is to fit a model over this list, and `pool` the results. `mice` then is using the `lm.mids` method included in the package.

```
fit <- with(data=imp, exp=lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl))
pool(fit)
pool(fit)$pooled[, 1:5]  # shortened
#                estimate         ubar            b            t dfcom
# (Intercept) 20.28615169 1.354978e+01 6.556134e+00 2.338398e+01    21
# age         -3.01670128 1.081655e+00 1.238383e-03 1.083512e+00    21
# hyp          1.89935232 4.074904e+00 2.092851e+00 7.214181e+00    21
# chl          0.04517373 3.813968e-04 5.113178e-06 3.890666e-04    21
```

And this is the point where you run into a problem, because there exists no `gwqs.mids` method (but there is a `glm.mids` method), and you probably need to write it yourself, or ask one of the package authors.

However, there is a `complete()` function included in `mice`, which yields a `"data.frame"`, with which you also could do pooled calculations. It should be used with care, though, i.e. using everything else than the `"long"` format (i.e. just one single imputation) would be very wrong.

```
complete(imp, "long")
#    .imp .id age  bmi hyp chl
# 1     1   1   1 30.1   1 187
# 2     1   2   2 22.7   1 187
# 3     1   3   1 27.2   1 187
# [...]
# 26    2   1   1 25.5   1 187
# 27    2   2   2 22.7   1 187
# 28    2   3   1 28.7   1 187
# [...]
class(complete(imp, "long"))
# [1] "data.frame"
```

The `".imp"` variable now indicates the number of the imputation, and you could calculate your `gwqs` model for each subset of `".imp"` indicators.

To pool the results now, you'd have to consider between and within variances (see [Rubin 1987:76](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470316696.fmatter)).

To elaborate further on this, though, would go too far for Stack Overflow. If you don't know how to do this, you'd need to consult a statistician, or ask at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) how to do that.

At least this would be a way to use `mice` and `gWQS` together.